# How do I fix spatial.distance.cosine function for machine learning?

Tags: python, machine-learning

I'm working on a machine learning class, but cam across a problem I can't solve using Google or Stack O. I'm using spatial.distance.cosine for a K-nerest neighbor example. However, when I call spatial.distance.cosine, I get the following key error: "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'map' and 'map'." I tried importing "from scipy.spatial import distance" and dropping "spatial," but that didn't work either. How can I fix this problem?[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may need to convert the input of `ComputeDistance()` into `list`s or `numpy.array`s.

Comment: so genresA = list(a[1])? That give me a result of "nan."

Comment: @Palmer_Eldrich `ComputeDistance(list(movieDict[2]), list(movieDict[4]))`